# EditText event handler to get notified that a key has been pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext

App need to know when a new key has been pressed during EditText is been used, filled. Is it any event hadler for it? In iOS for `UITextField` the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method is been used.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:on/> <----- some event handler need here but only onclick I see
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextChangedListener` for your `EditText` to receive event when editing the Text Field’s Text

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)  {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.i("TAG","text = "+yourEditText.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know why am I  not able to see `TextChangedListener` in the layout file? Added a screen shot to the question.

Comment: @János add it in your Java code (inside onCreate method of your Activity)

Comment: I see but from layout xml it is not possible?

Comment: @János I do think it is not possible in layout xml

Comment: Where can I read more about this JAVA language element u are using? U pass a block / unnamed method as listener, but this this method has 3 submethods? In JAVA  a method could have named 'submethods'? I know more about Swift, where I can read about this sturcture?

Comment: Got an exception using you code: `android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork` Do you have any idea?